# sql join tables IS NOT

Tags: sql

I need to get the data of all teachers who gives a course but does not have an assignement. I tried using inner or left join so if the name of the teacher is not in the table of the assignments it will show the data. If the name of the teacher is in the table of assignments it must not show the data. But I could not get it working.
What am I doing wrong?

```
select teachers.nameteacher, courses.namecourse, courses.codecourse
from teachers
inner join courses
on teachers.codecourse = courses.codecourse
left join assignments
on assignments.nameteacher = teachers.nameteacher
where teachers.nameteacher IS NULL
```

Comment: Hint:  `assignments.nameteacher is null`.

Answer (score 3):

filter should be from `assignments` table

```
SELECT t.nameteacher, 
       c.namecourse, 
       c.codecourse 
FROM   teachers t 
       INNER JOIN courses c 
               ON t.codecourse = c.codecourse 
       LEFT JOIN assignments a 
              ON a.nameteacher = t.nameteacher 
WHERE  a.nameteacher IS NULL --should be assignments
```

**Note :** start using `alias` names to make the query more readable

Answer (score 0):

The easy (and efficient) way, if you are using PostgreSQL or Microsoft SQL Server is to say:

```
select
    a.nameteacher,
    c.namecourse, 
    c.codecourse
from
    (
        select nameteacher from teachers
        except
        select nameteacher from assignments
    ) a
    join teachers b
    on a.nameteacher = b.nameteacher
    join courses c
    on b.codecourse = c.codecourse;
```

If you are using Oracle change "except" to "minus".

If you are using SQLite or MySQL you need to use one of the other suggestions because these don't support except or minus.